# How do I get Rails to exclude some bundled gems from plugin-loading?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, plugins, dependencies, bundler

I have a Rails application that uses Bundler for dependency management. I've got the following in my `Gemfile`:

```
# default group:
gem 'json'

group 'development' do
  gem 'my_profiler'
end

group 'test' do
  gem 'mocha'
end

group 'deployment' do
  gem 'foo'
end
```

I call `Bundler.setup(:default, RAILS_ENV.to_sym)` and `Bundler.require(:default, RAILS_ENV.to_sym)` in my initializers.

The problem is that since Bundler puts the gems into `vendor/bundle/`, Rails initializes *all* gems that have an `init.rb`, not just those for the current environment. How do I prevent Rails from automatically loading Foo's `init.rb`?

Comment: As a note, if you're using bundler, you should probably be using `Rails.root` instead of `RAILS_ROOT` and `Rails.env` instead of `RAILS_ENV`

Comment: Clear out the vendor/bundle/ folder. Or install the gems in a rvm gemset and then make sure you've got your enviroments right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of bundler are you using? recent ones should not install in vendor

Comment: 0.9.26. No immediate way to upgrade to 1.0 on this app.

Comment: I think older versions support --path, so bundle install --path different/location should work

Answer (score 11):

You can use the --without flag to exclude environments

```
$ bundle install --without development test
```

http://gembundler.com/groups.html

Comment: It isn't that _bundler_ is loading the gems; it's that Rails is globbing through the vendor directory and treating them as gem-plugins. Later versions of Bundler don't put gems in the vendor directory.